# Compilation error when comparing two strings with startsWith

Tags: java, string, jsp

I am developing for google app engine with JSP. And I need to compare two strings by startsWith() method in String class.

Here is the code I am working on.

```
    <% 
            String artist = "Surendra Perera";

            DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            Key songKey = KeyFactory.createKey("songs", 123454);
            // Run an ancestor query to ensure we see the most up-to-date
            // view of the songs.
            Query query = new Query("Song", songKey).addSort("Artist");
            //query.addFilter("Artist", Query.FilterOperator.IN, "Milton Mallawarachchi");
            List<Entity> songsList = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(30));
            if(songsList.isEmpty()){
            %>
            <p>There are no songs</p>
            <%
            }else{
%>
<ul class="playlist">
<%
            for(Entity song : songsList){
                if(artist.startsWith(song.getProperty("Artist"))){
%>

 <li><a href="<%= song.getProperty("Link") %>"><%= song.getProperty("Title") %>&#160;&#160;<span class="comment"><%= song.getProperty("Artist") %></span></a></li>

<% }}} %>
```

And here is the error i am getting....

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /search.jsp. Reason: 
    Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\SILICO~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\Jetty_127_0_0_1_8888_war____.g0qk00\jsp\org\apache\jsp\search_jsp.java:178: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method startsWith(java.lang.Object)
    [javac] location: class java.lang.String
    [javac]                 if(artist.startsWith(song.getProperty("Artist"))){
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] 1 error



Stacktrace:

Caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\SILICO~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\Jetty_127_0_0_1_8888_war____.g0qk00\jsp\org\apache\jsp\search_jsp.java:178: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method startsWith(java.lang.Object)
    [javac] location: class java.lang.String
    [javac]                 if(artist.startsWith(song.getProperty("Artist"))){
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling that it cannot find the given method `method startsWith(java.lang.Object)` in the `String` class. Please note that the error says `java.lang.Object` as method argument. This is indeed wrong. It has to be `java.lang.String`, see also the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

You have to change the return type of `song.getProperty()` from `Object` to `String`:

```
public String getProperty(String name) {
    // ...
}
```

**Or** to add a cast on `(String)` if it is *actually* of `String` type:

```
if (artist.startsWith((String) song.getProperty("Artist"))) {
    // ...
}
```

**Or** to use a fullworthy [Javabean](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info):

```
public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}
```

with

```
if (artist.startsWith(song.getArtist())) {
    // ...
}
```

Last but not least, this problem is **unrelated** to JSP. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class. Writing Java code in a JSP file is [not the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to get the basic concepts right.

Comment: Thank you! I casted out object to string. Since I cannot change the methods, because they are google app engine API methods. But your answer really helped me to figure out the problem.